# Odd behavior turning on LEDs using assmebly with MSP430FR4133

Tags: assembly, msp430

I am seeing some very odd behavior when I program my MSP430FR4133 board to turn on an LED using assembly language.

The LED will not come on when I run my assembly program.

The issue is that when I run a simple C program, the LED comes on and it works just as I programmed it to.

Now if I go back and run the assembly program, the LED will turn on! But if I stop the program and re-start the program the LED will no longer turn on again.

Is there any idea why this odd behavior could be happening?

Here is the assembly code I am using:

```
    ;MSP430 Assembler Code Template for use with TI Code Composer Studio

    .cdecls C,LIST,"msp430fr4133.h"       ; Include device header file


    .def    RESET                  

    .text                           ; Assemble into program memory.
    .retain                         ; Override ELF conditional linking
                                        ; and retain current section.
    .retainrefs                     ; And retain any sections that have
                                        ; references to current section.


     RESET       mov.w   #__STACK_END,SP   ; Initialize stackpointer
     StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW|WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer

     mov.w  #0x0001,&P1OUT
     mov.b  #0x0001,&P1DIR


     ; Main loop here


     InfLoop:
        jmp InfLoop
        NOP

     .global __STACK_END
     .sect   .stack


     ; Interrupt Vectors

      .sect   ".reset"                ; MSP430 RESET Vector
      .short  RESET
```

Here is the C code that I run on the board:

```c
      #include <msp430fr4133.h>

      int main(void)
      {
           PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5; // Disable the GPIO power-on default  high-impedance mode

           WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop the watchdog timer

           P1DIR = 0x01;
           P4DIR = 0x01;

           P1OUT = 0x01;
           P4OUT = 0x01;

           for(;;)
           {
           }

           return (0);
       }
```

Comment: Can you post your C program that does work, please?

Comment: Also, how are you loading this into the micro?

Comment: Hi RJP, I am using Code Composer Studio. I build the program and then I use the debuigger feature to load the program on the board and run it.

Comment: Take a look at this document. It's been too long since I've worked on an MSP430 and I didn't go deep enough to be able to write up an answer, but section 3.6 specifically relates to entry point, which I think might be your problem. http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau131l/slau131l.pdf

Comment: These are two *different* programs. Of course they behave differently! What parts of the assembler code did you actually write yourself?

Comment: I wrote them both myself. I apologize that the C code actually turns on 2 sets of LEDs versus my assembly code trying to turn on only one LED. It was in my troubleshooting phase that I removed the second LED from my assembly to try and understand what might be happening. Trust me, I wrote this myself and it is just simply "Hello World" style code. Sorry CL if I made you upset by not removing the second LED from the C code.

For clarity, one LED is tied to bit 0 of PORT 1 and the other LED is tied to bit 0 of PORT 4.

Comment: Thanks RJP! I am going to look into this and see if perhaps adding a call out in the assembly telling the program where to start will correct the issue.

Comment: There are more differences, such as using 8/16-bit accesses, or omitting the PM5CTL0 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The C code has this:

```c
  PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5; // Disable the GPIO power-on default  high-impedance mode
```

This initialization is missing from the assembler code; without it, none of the other pin configuration settings will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

See MSP430 user guide for LPM5 (Low Power Mode). Typical asm example:

```
...

StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW+WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop WDT
SetupGPIO   bis.b   #BIT0,&P1DIR
            bis.b   #BIT0,&P1OUT
UnlockGPIO  bic.w   #LOCKLPM5,&PM5CTL0      ; Disable the GPIO power-on default
                                            ; high-impedance mode to activate
                                            ; previously configured port settings
```

...